# Cannot render value of props from redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a redux state which is working fine in that my data is in the redux store. I can console.log it out with console.log(this.props) but I can't seem to render it out. It returns this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'somevalue' of undefined
```

Ususally I would map over props with a static block of html/jsx but I need this to be different html per loop so I'm trying to insert the values directly into the markup. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class UnitClass extends Component {
    state = {
        unit: {}
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Props is:', this.props); // shows correct values
        return (
            <ul>
               <li>{this.props.unit.somevalue.value1}</li>
               <li>{this.props.unit.somevalue.value2}</li>
               <li>{this.props.unit.somevalue.value3}</li>
               <li>{this.props.unit.somevalue.value4.someothervalue}</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    unit: state.setUnit.unit,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UnitClass);
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log('Props is:', this.props);`?

Comment: what is the console.log displaying ? why do you need the state?Also you might pass `null` to `connect(mapStateToProps, null)` for `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: I don't need the state if i can access the values directly somehow? I thought that was how you did it? :)

Comment: State and props are two different things, you don't need a state for all the props passed and vice versa.

Comment: If you are fetching your unit data from a server, there is a short period of time (the pending time) that somevalue is undefined and that leads to you getting the TypeError. its always a good idea to check the prop before using it or use default props.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 render() {
        console.log('Props is:', this.props); // shows correct values
        const {unit} = this.props;
        return (
            <ul>
            {unit.somevalue && unit.somevalue.map((value)=>{
            return value.someothervalue? <li>{value.someothervalue}</li>: <li>{value}</li>})
            }  
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

note: for conditional rendering, you can use `ternary operator` and if you have to deal with nested conditional rendering, then I would recommend [Higher Order Components](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-higher-order-components), and then probably [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)